# Removing hidden iframe: Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using an authentication library that uses invisible iframes in the background to renew the session. Once the session is renewed and a token is generated, I am using the following line piece of code to delete the iframes:

```
for (let i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
  if (iFrames[i].id.startsWith('adalRenewFrame')) {
   iFrames[i].remove();
  }
}
```

When I look at the 'elements' tab of my dev tools, I see that the iframes are indeed removed, BUT when I print a console log with something like:

```
window === window.parent
```

it logs a value saying 'false', which means the current window is not the parent window. So I suspect that the frame is actually not deleted because if it was deleted then I should see a true value for the above console log.
Any suggestions why it is printing a false value even after removing the iframes?